# Filter products in Magento by default weight attribute for Layered Navigation

Tags: php, magento, filter, layered-navigation

I have set up Layered Navigation for filtering products in Magento. To set an attribute as filterable, I have checked 'Show in Layered Nav' and 'Filterable with Results' in the admin area. However, these settings are not available for default weight attribute.

I am planning to create a custom weight attribute to make it filterable. It will be a select attribute as the products will have a fixed set of weights to which they will belong. The only issue with this is that the client will have to enter the weight in two places.

Is there a way to achieve filtering by weight using the default weight attribute OR Should I proceed with creating a custom attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is there a way to achieve filtering by weight using the default weight attribute ?` - No,

As the weight attribute by default is `text input field type` and to use attribute in layered navigation it should be a `dropdown` & further should be set `filterable with results and use as layered navigation`. And you can't change the default weight attribute/even other already saved attribute field type. So it's not possible with default `weight` attribute.

So basically, you would have to create another custom weight attribute which i would suggest you to create in range range. (by saying `Fixed set of weight` i guess you mean same). I would suggest you to call it `Weight range` as attribute label. And finally to confusion of attribute redundancy go to attribute set and manage both `weight` and `weight range` at same place and that would be good to go.